# Why can't a 3D point cloud be fed into a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I've been reading [this blog post](https://www.qwertee.io/blog/deep-learning-with-point-clouds/) about deep learning on point clouds and the author gives an example that is supposed to illustrate the two main problems with applying convolution to point clouds. According to him, the problems are variance to ordering (point clouds have no inherent natural ordering of their points) and desertion of shape (although there's no connectivity between the points, there is a topology defined on the whole set of points). Now, with his  picture of the example  I'll try to describe the issue I have with his example.

[image]

He gives three point clouds $A$, $B$ and $C$, each has four points, that are ordered in a certain manner ($A$ and $B$ have the same ordering, but different shapes; $B$ and $C$ have the same shape, but different orderings) and each point within a point cloud exhibits some feature (visualized by a different color). Then he convolves each point cloud with a 2x2-kernel s.t. $f(A) = f(B)$ and $f(B) \neq f(C)$. At this point, he states that convolution doesn't respect that a point cloud is unordererd (convolutions of $B$ and $C$ are not equal although only their ordering is different) and ignores the topological structures ($A$ and $B$ are clearly different w.r.t. their point positions but result in the same convolution).

But, the issue I see with this example is that he totally ignores the positions of the points in 3D space during convolution. If taken into account, convolution would yield different results, right? 
However, I can't think of a complete example that points out the same issues with convolution on point clouds. If anyone can, please share your insight, this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I agree that it's not exactly clear what the author was trying to depict with his "convolution" example. A better rephasing of the general task at hand might be "if we want to use convolution on pointclouds, then we'd better make sure it's invariant to the ordering of the points, and **makes use of the spatial location of points**".

And indeed there has been work along these lines: [Deep Parametric Continuous Convolutional Neural Networks](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers_backup/Wang_Deep_Parametric_Continuous_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf) among others.

PointNet does a pretty good job at permutation invariance, but doesn't really take advantage of the actual spatial locations of the points.

Comment: Thank you for the source, I will read upon it!

Comment: So this means that giving an example illustrating the aforementioned problems is pretty much impossible?